# Problem with MergeList during apt-get

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, 19.10, merge

Whenever I try to install something, I get the same error:

```
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/repo.mongodb.org_apt_ubuntu_dists_bionic_mongodb-org_4.0_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

I've tried to do the following:

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*    
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update
```

which was the solution proposed in many places, but it didn't work.
Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Have the same problem, seems that started yesterday, additionally the PGP key validation results in error : 
W: GPG error: https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.0 Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 68818C72E52529D4 MongoDB 4.0 Release Signing Key <packaging@mongodb.com>

Answer (score 7):

Remove mongo lists in:

`/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

then:

```
sudo rm -vf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: This worked for me, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I seemed to have to do the following, which is a combination of several posts I've seen that didn't work for me.

1: **Remove all mongo lists in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`**

```bsh
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d && sudo rm -rf mongo*
```

2: **Remove everything in `/var/lib/apt/lists/`**

```
sudo rm -rvf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

3: **Clean**

```
sudo apt clean
```

4: **Update**

```
sudo apt update
```

Answer (score 1):

Same problem Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

**Solution: Use the following commands in this order**

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
```

Move or remove mongodb-org-4.0.list, here I moved it with mv, use rm insteand to delete.

```
sudo mv mongodb-org-4.0.list /home/
```

(Remember to change the directory, provide where you want to put it so that you can still reuse it if things go wrong)

remove all lists

```
sudo rm -vf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

regenerate them

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now you can use again Software Updater.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the problematic repositories, then try removing the MergeList, and then regenerate it:

```
sudo rm -vf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update
```